# Identify this shaft driven bike for me

Tags: identify-this-bike, shaft

[image]

I can't identify the manufacturer nor the year it was produced.

It has a serial number on the frame, just above the front fork, something like 93042829 or so what (peculiarity: the numbers are engraved head down).

So, can anybody help me, please?

Comment: I really like the way this bike looks with the shaft integrated into the frame. Probably makes it harder to maintain, but I think the looks would offset that because I don't think shaft drives require a lot of maintenance.

Comment: @Kibbee - Looks aside, it seems like it would have some pretty obvious advantages for a commuter bike, especially in wet climates... doesn't look like there's a gear hub, interestingly...

Comment: @junkyardsparkle  I wonder if its a fixie, photo's a bit small to see any sort of freewheel mechanism.   Ludwig its a nice looking bike.   Can you please post some more photos (specifically bottom bracket, shaft area and rear wheel hub) and confirm whether it has any gearing or a freewheel ?

Comment: Thanks for all comments; I have more photos,  Criggie: the hell is I don't know how...need help to post

Comment: well, it seems I found out how to post more photos..rsss. Yes, Criggie, it is a fixie (no gearing)

Comment: If it's a fixed gear, why does it have both front and rear brakes?

Comment: @R.Chung  Some locations require two independent hand brakes, and the transmission doesn't count as hand-operated.

Comment: With those pedals there is no way it's a fixie. Single speed yes, fixed gear no.  Ludwig if you stand next to the bike and push it a few feet do the crank and pedals spin or do they stay in position with a gentle click click click sound?

Comment: @zipzit yes, now I realized it's not a fixie, but a single speed. It really makes thal "click, click, click" sound...sorry for the mistake and misunderstandig. (my motherland's language is portuguese and therefore sometimes I'm confused with some english terms...sorry).

Comment: Can you tell us where in the world it is?  What I see in the photo appears to be a modern reproduction of an older style, so a recent retro bike.  The short head tube implies modern manufacturing, rather than the much longer head tubes on older bikes.   Does it have a QR on the wheels or on the seat clamp?  The carrier/rack looks particularly crappy design with a very low load level.   Have a look over the cranks, pedals, brake arms and cable, and everywhere for any sort of brand names.  I'm expecting you'll find none, so its a noname from asia.  Don't let that put you off riding it though!

Comment: Cantilever brakes, quill stem, metal brake levers date the design to be at least 10 years old, probably 20.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the integrated shaft and the style of bike it could be from [Arcade](http://www.arcadecycles.eu/). I can't see the bike in their current catalogue, but that's hardly surprising. Maybe if you contacted them directly they could help you out.

This is the key part of the only shaft drive bike in their 2016 range:

[image: Arcade "1903" shaft driven bicycle]

Answer (score -1):

I think this Chainless drive aka "Sussex Drive" I came across a brand or model called Dynamic which had the same odd bend in the top tube.

[Review: Dynamic “Crosstown 7” Shaft-Drive Bicycle](http://www.bikecommuters.com/2007/07/26/review-dynamic-crosstown-7-shaft-drive-bicycle/)

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing that bike at that link - your link shows a separate chainstay and shaft, and no bent top tube. I edited in an image from the article to clarify - can you delete that and add the one you think matches, please? Surely it can't have shifted in the 18 minutes since your answer?